# Removing empty elements from php array

Tags: php, arrays

Im looking for a way to remove empty elements from an array.
Im aware of array_filter() which removes all empty values.

The thing is that i consider a string containing nothing but spaces, tabs and newlines also to be empty.

So what is best used in this case?

Comment: `array_filter($array, function ($v) { return (bool)trim($v); });`

Comment: perfect hindmost, thank you.

Comment: @Kristian Rafteseth You could choose this answer as "accepted" if you want to express your "thank".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `trim()` in callback for `array_filter`:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function ($v) { return (bool)trim($v); });
```

Or shorter version (with implicit type-casting):

```
$array = array_filter($array, 'trim');
```

Answer (score 0):

[php empty()](https://www.php.net/empty)

> bool empty ( mixed $var )
>
> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
> considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
> empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Something like should do:

```
foreach($array as $key => $stuff)
{
    if(empty(stuff))
    {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
$array  = array_values($array );// to reinstate the numerical indexes.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be late to answer but it is for those who may have interest in other ways to solve this. It is my own way of doing it.

```
function my_array_filter($my_array)
{
    $final_array = array();
    foreach ( $my_array as $my_arr ) 
    {
        //check if array element is not empty
        if (!empty($my_arr)) $final_array[] = $my_arr;
    }
    //remove duplicate elements
    return array_unique( $final_array );
}
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: That is an awesome code you got there sir and I must say it really helped me on something i have been working on